# Nested NSArray for loop won't loop in nested fashion

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsarray

I've been learning Objective-C for five days and I have only 2 weeks of prior programming experience so please make answers as simple as possible.

I'm doing an exercise in a book that asks me to generate a list of proper names that are also regular words. To do this I have am running a for loop for each proper name from a `NSArray` proper name object. Within that for loop I have a nested for loop testing each name against each word in an `NSArray` regular word object using the `caseInsensitiveCompare` method.

Here is my code:

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        //Gets the sting with proper names
        NSString *propername = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/propernames" encoding:
        NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        //Gets the string with regularwords
        NSString *inpropername = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words" encoding:
                                NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        NSArray *proper = [propername componentsSeparatedByString:@"/n"];
        NSArray *inproper = [inpropername componentsSeparatedByString:@"/n"];

        for (NSString *n in proper){
            NSLog(@"%@", n);
            for(NSString *i in inproper){
                NSLog(@"%@", i);
                if ([n caseInsensitiveCompare:i] == NSOrderedSame)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Yahooo! Got One! %@", n);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of the for loops running in a nested fashion they are running in a sequential fashion. The output is like this:

```
Aaron  
all the names...  
Yvonne  
a  
all the regular words....  
Zyzzogeton
```

Any ideas for why the nested for loop is not running in a nested fashion?

Comment: My guess is that you're not showing us something.

Comment: The "/n" is suspicious… I guess you meant "\n"

Comment: You clearly haven't added all your code, as nowhere in the code shown do you print "all the names..." or "all the regular words...".

Comment: "all the names" is just a way to say that "here I see all the names", it's not part of what is actually displayed. :-)

Comment: Julien you were right - it should have been "\n", because of that each object only contained one big long string. That's one problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

The code is correct except you are not breaking the files into words since you are using "/n" instead of "\n".

This means that each array contains exactly one element which is a string with all the words in it.